# I want to make an image grid of 7 images in bootstrap 4 / HTML5

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image grid of 7 images but the image size should not be fixed, I have used col classes but I am not getting the result that I want, Is anybody knows how can I do it, or tell me something about wrapper class?

Comment: Please share whatt you did.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you just need to make sure you have added class `.flex-nowrap` to the row here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/1994/